# How would I represent managing a pirate ship in Reign's Company rules?

Tags: realm-management, reign

I'm unclear on how to represent managing a pirate ship using [Reign's Company rules](http://www.gregstolze.com/Company_Reference.pdf). How would they be applied?

Comment: Since this is just about using the rules for their normal purpose, I clarified that and removed the [homebrew] tag.

Comment: Quick question: do you have a copy of *Reign* (or the *Reign Enchiridion*) to refer to for the actual Company rules, or are you only reading that quick-reference PDF you linked to?

Comment: I will buy a copy of Reign, but now I only have the quick-reference PDF

Comment: The quick-reference is just a reference and does not contain the rules you need to know to use an answer that might be posted here. I'm going to close this question as premature. Once you have read the actual Company rules, then you can ask about anything that's unclear about them, if you still have questions.